# fetching value of specific key from json response

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

how can I store a specific value of a key from json response into a variable

```
{
   "results": [
    {
      "name": ryan,
      "roll_id": 64,
      "class_id": 310,
      "net_id": 95,
    },
  ],
};
```

above is the json response :-

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
val ListV = gson.fromJson(body, HomeClass::class.java)
```

after these 2 lines I'm totally clueless how to do it I've gone through Internet but It was hard for me to understand how to proceed further.

Comment: Better to read something: https://www.journaldev.com/2321/gson-example-tutorial-parse-json

Answer (score 0):

Your Json Structure will be

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "Amiyo",
      "roll_id": 1,
      "class_id": 10,
      "net_id": 91
    },
   {
       ....
   }

  ]
}
```

Data class should be

```
data class HomeClass (

    @SerializedName("results") val results : List<Results>
)

data class Results (

    @SerializedName("name") val name : String,
    @SerializedName("roll_id") val roll_id : Int,
    @SerializedName("class_id") val class_id : Int,
    @SerializedName("net_id") val net_id : Int
)
```

**fromJson**

```
val listData = gson.fromJson(jsonData, HomeClass::class.java)
```

Then

```
 val totalSize = 0 until listData!!.size
  if(totalSize.size>0)
    {
        for (i in totalSize)
        {
                 //Your Code i==Position
        }
     }
```